# Escape the dot in PHP sscanf?

Tags: php, scanf

This doesn't work:

```
list($value) = sscanf('foo.bar','%s.bar');
echo $value; //foo.bar
```

While this does:

```
list($value) = sscanf('foo bar','%s bar');
echo $value; //foo
```

Any suggestions are really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a basic (negated) character class instead of `s` as in:

```
list($value) = sscanf('foo.bar','%[^.].bar');
echo $value; //foo
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use explode instead of sscanf() for what you want to do.

```
$str = "foo.bar";
list($value1,$value2) = explode(".",$str);
print $value1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this was just an simplified example and it's possible that multiple variables or characters occur.

Answer (score 2):

[I think it by design](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=7793). It is trivial to use `preg_match` here, to be honest.

Comment: Thank you, i'll go with preg_match()

Comment: I don't see how that bug is relevant - OP doesn't have any quotes.  Also, it's advisable never to use regex where plain ole' string ops will do the job.

Comment: @Chris: let's see what the comment from php developer says there: "Strings for `scanf` are delimited by whitespace. For what you
need, use `ereg` or `preg_match`."